Reprojecting to rotated orthographic projection in rasterio
I have some DEMs in a lunar polar stereographic projection (from LOLA). I would like to reproject them to a orthographic projection with a custom azimuth rotation using rasterio. I can pretty easily create an azimuthal orthographic CRS with rasterio:
from rasterio.crs import CRS

def get_ortho_proj(lat, lon):
    return CRS.from_string(f"+proj=ortho +lat_0={lat} +lon_0={lon} +R=1737400")

And I can project no problem:
# yields a new numpy array ortho_data with the dataset
# reprojected to orthographic with the specified lat, lon origin

dst_crs = get_ortho_proj(lat, lon)

dataset = rasterio.open('LDEM_80S_80M.LBL')
orig_data = dataset.read(1)

transform, width, height = rasterio.warp.calculate_default_transform(dataset.crs, dst_crs, dataset.width, dataset.height, \
                             left=dataset.bounds.left, right=dataset.bounds.right, top=dataset.bounds.top, bottom=dataset.bounds.bottom)

ortho_data = np.zeros((width, height), dtype=orig_data.dtype)

reproject(orig_data, ortho_data, src_transform=dataset.transform, src_crs=dataset.crs, \
          dst_transform=transform, dst_crs=dst_crs, resampling=Resampling.bilinear, dst_nodata=np.iinfo(np.int16).min)

However, the PROJ4 string does not support specifying an azimuth rotation - it always defaults to north at the origin point. I would like to be able to specify a custom azimuth rotation - I will be doing sun and Earth visibility analysis, and it is much easier if I can rotate the DEM such that the rows align with the sun or Earth respectively.
I figured I could modify the output of calculate_default_transform with an Affine.rotation, but I've had nothing but grief doing so. Here's my current attempt (after many previous failures):
def rotate_and_center2(src_transform, src_bounds, rot_deg):
    # compute bounding box in image coordinates
    col1, row1 = ~src_transform*(src_bounds[0], src_bounds[1])
    col2, row2 = ~src_transform*(src_bounds[0], src_bounds[3])
    col3, row3 = ~src_transform*(src_bounds[2], src_bounds[1])
    col4, row4 = ~src_transform*(src_bounds[2], src_bounds[3])
    ul_rowcol = (np.min( (row1, row2, row3, row4) ), np.min( (col1, col2, col3, col4) ))
    lr_rowcol = (np.max( (row1, row2, row3, row4) ), np.max( (col1, col2, col3, col4) ))
    # compute rotation in image coordinates
    image_center_row = 0.5*(lr_rowcol[0] - ul_rowcol[0])
    image_center_col = 0.5*(lr_rowcol[1] - ul_rowcol[1])
    # compute rotate transform
    rotate = Affine.translation(-1.0*image_center_col, -1.0*image_center_row)\
             *Affine.rotation(rot_deg)\
             *Affine.translation(image_center_col, image_center_row)
    net_transform = ~(~src_transform*rotate)
    # compute new bounds
    col1, row1 = ~net_transform*(src_bounds[0], src_bounds[1])
    col2, row2 = ~net_transform*(src_bounds[0], src_bounds[3])
    col3, row3 = ~net_transform*(src_bounds[2], src_bounds[1])
    col4, row4 = ~net_transform*(src_bounds[2], src_bounds[3])
    ul_rowcol_xf = (np.min( (row1, row2, row3, row4) ), np.min( (col1, col2, col3, col4) ))
    lr_rowcol_xf = (np.max( (row1, row2, row3, row4) ), np.max( (col1, col2, col3, col4) ))
    # compute shift
    net_transform_shifted = ~(~src_transform*rotate*Affine.translation(-1.0*ul_rowcol_xf[1], -1.0*ul_rowcol_xf[0]))
    return net_transform_shifted, int(lr_rowcol_xf[1] - ul_rowcol_xf[1]), int(lr_rowcol_xf[0] - ul_rowcol_xf[0])

I am invoking this as (with an example 45 degree rotation angle):
transform, width, height = rasterio.warp.calculate_default_transform(dataset.crs, dst_crs, dataset.width, dataset.height, \
                             left=dataset.bounds.left, right=dataset.bounds.right, top=dataset.bounds.top, bottom=dataset.bounds.bottom)
transform, width, height = rotate_and_center2(transform, dataset.bounds, 45.0)

No matter what, however, the output is always at least a little bit clipped at the edges:

Any thoughts? I assume I'm making a fundamental error with my transform logic, but I don't know what it is. I am of course open to other solutions.

My thoughts (though I'm not risking Bounty creds on it) is that the transform is indeed working, but your plt boundary is based on the original "dataset.bounds" which of course leads to the clipping.  Other thoughts is DON"T USE 45 degrees, because we cannot see Sin() VS Cos() when they are equal....TRY 30 degrees to ensure affine is working. Final thought: should the function return be [0] items then [1] items (x, y) ordered pair-wise? -- it looks like your output is (Y,X)  Hope these help.
